# Cannot get result from String.EqualIgnoreCase comparison

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to get a comparison between two string variables representing emails. It only works if both strings matches with the same letters case, even though I'm using 'equalIgnoreCase()' method.

Here is a snippet:

```
    String Query = "SELECT Email FROM Gmail WHERE Email = ?" 

    boolean Flag = false; // the method returns boolean
    String email = null; // to use with SQL query

    try {
        Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EmailsDB");
        PreparedStatement PS = Con.prepareStatement(Query);
        PS.setString(1, Email);

        ResultSet RS = PS.executeQuery();

        while ( RS.next() ) {
            email = RS.getString("Email");

            if ( Email.equalsIgnoreCase(email) )
                Flag = true;

       }
    }
   // Email: a parameter string to check the user email entry.
```

Expected:
The method returns 'true' if there's a matching email in the DB, thus discarding user entry.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Where do you get from `Email`? What's its value? I only see an `email`.

Comment: It doesn't return true if the strings matches, unless it's exactly the same

Comment: "// Email: a parameter string to check the user email entry."

Comment: Have you validated your `Email` input? Does it contain whitespaces, is it `null` etc.

Comment: Yes, it's validated

Comment: Could you provide an example of something that doesn't work and it should and an example of something that does return true?

Comment: If `equalsIgnoreCase` is returning false, it's likely (weird characters aside) that your strings are not equal ignoring case. Perhaps you can produce a [mcve] with known values for `Email` and `email` so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for providing minimum info. (first time :) ), here's an example:
The database contains emails for users, let's assume the DB contains the following emails:
- Test@gmail.com
- Test2@gmail.com

The method should return true if the user entered an email that's already exist in the DB.

if the user entered 'Test@gmail.com' the method works correctly.
if the user entered 'TEST@gmail.com' the method doesn't work resulting in redundant email in the DB.

Comment: @d3f4lt If the operands were `"TEST@gmail.com"` and `"Test@gmail.com"` then `equalsIgnoreCase` _would_ return true. The problem in your code is not with `equalsIgnoreCase`. It may be with getting the relevant row from your database (if your database is case sensitive). Without a [mcve], it is impossible to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that one of your strings has some leading or trailing whitespace (i.e. you have "test@gmail.com    " instead of "test@gmail.com"). If that's the case, then you can use String.trim() to remove the whitespace and then compare the strings:

```
String Query = "SELECT Email FROM Gmail WHERE Email = ?" 

boolean Flag = false; // the method returns boolean
String email = null; // to use with SQL query

try {
    Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EmailsDB");
    PreparedStatement PS = Con.prepareStatement(Query);
    PS.setString(1, Email);

    ResultSet RS = PS.executeQuery();

    while ( RS.next() ) {
        email = RS.getString("Email");

        if ( Email.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(email.trim()) )
            Flag = true;

   }
}
```